# Add files to zip archive preservinf directory structure

Tags: bash, cygwin, php-ziparchive

I want to add a list of files (a text file contains the list of these files i.e. full windows path of each file) , i want to use cygnus win to add files to a zip archive while preserving the directory structure

Comment: i managed to do it , ty for the reply , i didnt knew about tar command before since i am new to bash , this was done on cyg-win

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
tar cvf yourarchive.tar --files-from /dev/null
for file in $(cat YOURLIST); do tar rf yourarchive.tar $file; done
gzip yourarchive.tar
```

The loop would append all files found in the textfile to your tarfile.